# Send object from node.js to ejs, not [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

If you use node.js and ejs and render JavaScript object to ejs, the resultant HTML page has the following syntax:

```
[object Object]
```

despite the fact that my object is as follows:

```
[{"a": 3, "b": 10}, {"c":3, "d":20}, {"e":1, "f":55}]
```

However, I want to render the object itself (object literal if I understand it correctly), not the useless `[object Object]`.

So how can I render it properly? `res.render("index", {result: listOfObject.valueOf()})` didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[object Object]` is what you get when you call `.toString()` on an anonymous object. This is implicitly done when you concatenate with another string (e.g. `"my object: " + {a:'b'}`).

If you want to get the output you're looking for, you need to use

`JSON.stringify(yourObjectHere)`

Which prints it all out nicely.

Answer (score 3):

```
res.render("index", { result: JSON.stringify(listOfObject) });
```